# How to force exactly one properties of two to be set?

Tags: json, jsonschema

The requirement is to have both of the keys in a map (response) but only **one** of them can be null. Please, have a look at examples.

Invalid:

```
{
   "data": {},
   "error": {}
}
```

Valid:

```
{
   "data": null,
   "error": {}
}
```

Valid:

```
{
   "data": {},
   "error": null
}
```

How can I declare a JSON schema that will fulfill this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your samples it seems that one of them "Should" be null. If this is the case, you might use oneOf and define two schemas, one requiring a not null "data" property value and a null "error" property value and viceversa.

You might also consider not include "data" or "error" properties when they are null. You can use also "oneOf" in this case.

Comment: Can You also please point me to the JSON schema docs and good validator?